# How come I keep getting False when checking list item

Tags: python, list, types, set, boolean

I put together a set of types found in a list, then converted that to a list.

```
s = set() 
for i in ['hungry', 'delicious', 'desserts']:
    s.add(type(i))
l = list(s)
```

Now let's say I want to check if the first element in `l` says 'string'. When I request `print(l[0])`, I get `<class 'str'>` as the output.

But when I ask if `l[0] == "<class 'str'>"`, I get `False`. Same thing when I ask if `l[0] == 'str'`.

What do I need to change in the code to get it to say `True`?

Comment: You are looking for `isinstance`.

Comment: You are comparing a class with the string representing the class.

Comment: `s` contains types, and so does `l`. So you need to check if `l[0] == str` (the class, not a string)

Comment: `l[0]` is not a string object (it is a `type` object).  When you do print, its `__str()__` method is invoked, and returns the string `"<class 'str'>"`.  You could e.g. test `l[0] == str`, but if you still have access to the original object of which you extracted the type  (e.g. `'hungry'`), then you can use `isinstance(foo, str)` to test if `foo` is a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the quotes around:

```
l[0] == str
```

also works. `'str'` is just another string, not a type.